# Past continuous or simple?

Tags: grammar

The team ( wore - were wearing ) uniforms while they played the practice match.

I know they might both be right (they felt like they were both right) but which one feels more correct to you?

Thankyou

Comment: In AmE, using a plural verb for a group acting in concert is ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't remember where i read this, but i believe i can say "the family want /wants to play."

Comment: Since nouns denoting a group of individuals (such as team, class and family) are allowed to be used as plural while acting together in British English, you can say "the family wants to play" or "the family want to play" but this is to be singular in USA and elsewhere since all such nouns are grammatically singular in a strict sense of the term.

Comment: I might prefer  *were wearing* because the conjunction *while* means "during the time that"; in other words   it refers to the   duration of an event,   something that the progressive also does.

Comment: I might prefer "The team wore uniforms....". But either will work. And, yes, in AmE something like "the family want to play" sounds *really* (and I mean *really*) off. It would be "the family wants to play".

Comment: @EnglishStudent: Where do you get the "and elsewhere" in "USA and elsewhere"?  British English isn't a physical location.  There are many other English-speaking countries where the local standard is more likely to reflect BrE than AmE.  So your phrase "and elsewhere" doesn't tell us which countries you mean.  If you simply meant "in the countries that speak American English", that is surely implicit and doesn't need to be stated.  Instead of saying "in USA", you could have simply said "in American English".

Comment: Even in AmE, some collective nouns - including "couple" and "family" - sometimes take plural verbs.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-couple-singular-or-plural and http://sites.utexas.edu/legalwriting/2017/06/05/collective-nouns-singular-or-plural/

Comment: 'USA and elsewhere' doesn't mean American English: in the way Indians and many other nationality people use English (not any specific dialect) the collective nouns like team, committee, government tend to be *treated as singular* and British English is the exception treating them as plural, @rjpond. This is also exceptional in that the local standards in India *otherwise reflect British English!*: the explanation seems to be that such nouns were originally considered singular in British English but later evolved into plural form, to reflect the 'collective' nature of their activities, I think.

Comment: I understand both forms of concord are in use in AusE and NZE as well as IrishE, and CanE seems to use plural concord a bit more than AmE - not to mention the fact that even AmE allows plural concord sometimes, according to M-W.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @rjpond. What about non native speakers from so many other nations when they use collective nouns like team, committee and government?

Comment: @EnglishStudent: Generally non-native speakers are interested in learning how native speakers speak, rather than learning what patterns are typical of fellow non-native speakers.  However, native BrE speakers, too, sometimes treated collective nouns as singular.  The question is too broad to be addressed in this comments section, I fear.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, @rjpond and I shall try to develop a proper question that addresses this matter.

Answer (score 1):

"The team wore" is good enough unless you have any special reason to use "were wearing." Why? Because 'they wore' matches the tense of 'while they played' which is simple past tense. That "keeps things simple."

> The team **wore** uniforms while they **played** the practice match.

However it is not necessary that both verbs are of the same tense, as long as the combination of tenses is grammatically sensible.

By the way, as the member pointed out in comment, "the team" is often considered plural for these purposes in British English and generally singular in USA and elsewhere, so you need to keep that in mind while writing "the team **were** wearing...while **they** played" or choosing "the team **was** wearing"...while **it** played" -- and also take care to avoid mixing a singular with a plural!

Comment: So do the tenses HAVE to match, or is it just preferable ? So saying "the team were wearing uniforms while they were playing the match" is better than "they wore" in this case?

Comment: Good question! The tenses dont HAVE to match, at least in this specific case. It is not necessary or even preferable here, and the choice is a matter of taste; the combination only needs to be grammatically correct. 'Wore(...)while they played' is simple and sounds good. 'Were wearing(...) while they played' is OK but only if you are particular. 'Were wearing(...)while they **played**' is better than 'were wearing(...)while they were **playing**' which may be grammatically correct but sounds tedious and awkward!

Comment: You are welcome! You can learn a lot more about the combination of tenses by searching under 'questions' on this website.